# JSON string with custom dynamically columns. Appending in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Have made the following piece of code

```
        var content = @ " {
          ""
          data "": {
            ""
            id "": 1000000,
            ""
            firstName "": ""
            John "",
            ""
            lastName "": ""
            Doe "",
            ""departments"": [2245],
            ""employeeGroups"": [],
            ""
            custom_186549 "": {
              ""
              name "": ""
              Pension_overenskomst "",
              ""
              type "": ""
              Boolean "",
              ""
              value "": false
            },
            ""
            custom_186550 "": {
              ""
              name "": ""
              Pension 1. arbejdsdag "",
              ""
              type "": ""
              Boolean "",
              ""
              value "": false
            }
          }
        }
        ";

        JObject names = JObject.Parse(content);

        IEnumerable < JToken > CustomColumnsFirst = names.SelectTokens("$.data");

        foreach(JToken item in CustomColumnsFirst) {
          Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        IEnumerable < JToken > CustomColumnsNames = names.SelectTokens("$.data.*.name");
        IEnumerable < JToken > CustomColumnValues = names.SelectTokens("$.data.*.value");
```

I'm stuck here, managed to get the names and values into an JToken "Array" but kinda need both a way to combine the CustomColumnNames and the CustomColumnValues, but then also appending them back onto the main data.
The content of the "customs" are inditical though but the custom name itself varies. The order of the values inside the customers are random aswell though

I'm quite new to C# coding, so don't know much of the basics yet.

I would need to return a json string with this format without typing in the "custom" column name as that one can differ based on what the API returns:

```json
{
   "data":{
      "id":1000000,
      "firstName":"John",
      "lastName":"Doe",
      "departments": [2245],
      "employeeGroups": []
      "Pension_overenskomst":false,
      "Pension 1. arbejdsdag":false
   }
}
```

Comment: Is it an option to change your json so that the custom items are an array of objects instead of individual objects with unpredictable names?

Comment: @crowcoder, can't change anything, this is how i receive the response from the API unfortunately. The content of the "customs" are inditical though but the custom name itself varies.

Comment: That's an unfortunate misuse of json. At a glance it looks like Serge has shown you what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
var data = ((JObject)JObject.Parse(content)["data"]);

JObject items = new JObject();
foreach (var item in data.Properties())
if ( item.Name.Contains("custom"))
//or, thanks to iSR5
 if ( item.Name.StartsWith("custom"))
        if (item.Name.StartsWith("custom"))
        {
          if ((string)item.Value["type"] == "Boolean")
                items.Add((string)item.Value["name"], item.Value["value"]);
            else if ((string)item.Value["type"] == "Text") items.Add("name", item.Value["value"]);
        }
else
        items.Add(item.Name, item.Value););


JObject newData = new JObject();
newData.Add("data", items);
content = newData.ToString();
//or
 content = newData.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);
```

new  content json

```
{
  "data": {
    "id ": 1000000,
    "firstName ": "John",
    "lastName ": "Doe",
    "departments": [
      2245
    ],
    "employeeGroups": [],
    "Pension_overenskomst": false,
    "Pension 1.arbejdsdag": false,
    "name": "John Doe"
  }
}
```

Comment: `item.Name.Contains("custom")` would be better if changed to `StartWith`

Comment: Serge solution looks like it's doing the trick!

Comment: @iSR5 It's StartsWith right? Otherwise it doesn't seem to be a function

Comment: Do you know how i can return the JObject newData back into a jsonstring? Need to upload the result in a flat .json file

Comment: @AlexanderMilland content = newData.ToString(); I updated my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242630/discussion-between-alexander-milland-and-serge).

Comment: The "else
        items.Add(item.Name, item.Value););" doesn't work when e.g. employeeGroups contain an empty array like here fyi.

Comment: @AlexanderMilland thanks, but  I am tested my code and everything is working properly

Comment: You were correct, issue was two "custom" columns both having the same child element in "name".